# Postgresql Query to Redshift Conversion

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am trying to convert a PostgreSQL query to a Redshift query, that I successfully run in pgadmin. However, when I try to run this I get the following error in redshift, and I have commented the line where I get the error in the code:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "select" Position: 211
```

I have tried a few things from assigning aliases to changing the query a bit, but unfortunately, I am not able to fix this. Can someone please guide me as I have to convert a few PostgreSQL queries that are complex in nature. I think the error has to do with the way we are joining and doing a nested select statement, if anyone knows how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated!

```
select hc.referrals.*, latest_history.created_at
              from hc.referrals
              join hc.referral_statuses
              on hc.referral_status_id = hc.referrals.id
              left join lateral (

                **select hc.referral_status_histories.created_at**
                from hc.referral_status_histories
                where hc.referral_status_histories.referral_id = hc.referrals.id
                order by hc.referral_status_histories.created_at desc
                limit 1
              ) latest_history on true

              where hc.referral_statuses.task = true
              and hc.referrals.job_id = 501
              
and (
                hc.referrals.archived_at IS NULL 
                or hc.referral_statuses.title LIKE 'Send breakup email%'
              )
              and hc.referrals.deleted_at IS NULL
              and (
                (hc.referral_statuses.position < 3)
                and hc.referrals.source NOT IN (4, 6)
                or (hc.referral_statuses.title LIKE 'Send breakup email%')
              )
              and (hc.referral_statuses.delay is null or latest_history.created_at + (hc.referral_statuses.delay::INTEGER * interval '1 minute')  <= current_timestamp);
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the query should be doing.

Comment: Table aliases would make reading easier.

Comment: When I give the table aliases, redshift says that the relation "a" does not exist.